# Error when inserting data from csv to Postgres table

Tags: python, postgresql, psycopg2

I have a csv file uploaded in AWS S3 and I plan to update a table in the Postgres DB using the below code

```
cursor.execute("""export PGPASSWORD='db_password'; psql -h hostname -U username -d db_name -c "\COPY table_name FROM 's3://filepath.csv' with DELIMITER ','""")
```

This throws an error:

```
psycopg2.errors.SyntaxError: syntax error at or near "export"
LINE 1: export PGPASSWORD='db_password'; psql -h hostname
```

Comment: `cursor.execute()` executes SQL queries and not bash commands. You likely meant: `cursor.execute("COPY table_name FROM...")`.

Comment: @alecxe, I thought that works for redshift only.

Comment: With psycopg2, you should use the built in copy support: https://www.psycopg.org/docs/usage.html#using-copy-to-and-copy-from

Answer (score 0):

That command is a bash command, not a postgres command.